# OpenAPI definition files per version per area in .NET Core using Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am using the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning/) with Swashbuckle, and Swashbuckle generates a definition file per version using the startup config:

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    // generate endpoint for each version
    foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
    }
});
```

In the Swagger UI this gives:
[image: Definition per version in SwaggerUI]

With the URL being:

```
api\v1\fruit
```

I want to introduce an `Area` into the API route by attributes on the controllers:

```cs
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Area("Private")]
```

So that the OpenAPI definition files are split by area as well:
[image: Swagger definitions per area]

With URL:

```
api\public\v1\fruit
api\private\v1\fruit
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you, although I'm afraid it's not a complete fix.

https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/516#issuecomment-561348964

It seems that if you use the format 'options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";'
Then the last part of the versioning can be alphanumeric, i.e. you should be able to write version like so;

[ApiVersion( "3.0.session" )]
[ApiVersion( "3.0.authoring" )]

Further down in the [tread](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/516#issuecomment-743218359), another suggests a substition configuration that will allow you to switch the names so you have the version and names reversed in the swagger docs, i.e. so ApiVersion 3.0.session becomes `session-v3.0` .